# IE10 artifacts appear when using alpha png with background-repeat

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, png, transparency

I'm having the following problem in IE10 under Windows8, just using plain and simple div with a repeat-x background and when using a transparent png artifacts appear.

Results:
http://s18.postimg.org/9tn3dlsqx/artifacts.png

Here's sample code:

CSS

```
div.field { height: 762px; background-image: url(../img/background_grass.png) repeat-x; width: 5000px; left: -700px; position: absolute;  }
div.graphics { overflow: hidden; width: 3840px; position: absolute; background: url(../img/path_1.png); height: 640px; top: 315px; left: -1000px;}
```

And the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyForest - Идея по-чисто</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="graphics"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Only on IE 10 under Windows 8? Also, could you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. Try changing the height or width of your image.

It seems to happen with large png background images that have a certain height to width ratio when they are repeated. In my case the image is 2000px wide by 1000px tall and the right side of the background ends up overlapping by 88 pixels (the background ends up being 2088 pixels. In my case I am using a transparent png with wrapping graphics that are slightly transparent. Even stranger, if I make the image 2000px by 2000px the problem goes away.

It's too bad... I was hoping IE had improved with version 10 and we wouldn't have to deal with these kind of quirks anymore.

Comment: Thank you man, I also figured that the problem was with the image, by tweaking the place where the tile is repeated in photoshop it seems to have fixed the problem.