# CSS: weird tiling bug in Internet Explorer (any version)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, png

So, I've got this rather large overlay that I need to tile, and everything works as expected until I get to Internet Explorer. On Internet Explorer when it "tiles" horizontally, I get these odd lines that aren't a part of the original document.

The offending HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #CCCCEF;
        }

        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/177486/grit.tiny.png');
            background-position: -900px 0%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Here's an image showing what it does:

[image]

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derekaug/hwsdonhp/)

Comment: OMG, wtf is going on there? can you try to set background-position: 0 0?

Comment: The `background-position` bit is just so the bug shows up in the iframe on JSFiddle. Changing it doesn't change anything.

Comment: OK, if the weird IE thing is showing on jsFiddle, i'd say save your code to a html file and load it directly, and see.

Comment: It's actually showing on this website I'm working on. I just extracted the relevant markup and styles as an example for people here. :)

Comment: Well, looks like the problem doesn't related to the code above to me. I believe there is something else you need to look at on the actual page you're working on.

Comment: Don't forget there is also Developer Tools on IE no matter which version, it maybe not as good, but it works for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely an IE bug. Semi-answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112494/ie10-artifacts-appear-when-using-alpha-png-with-background-repeat). Basically, images with alpha and certain aspect ratios on Windows 8+ (IE 10/11) will reproduce this.  Switching to a 1:1 aspect ratio image (in this case) will avoid tiling bug. Not a great solution since you have to modify your image, but if you can modify image dimensions- it works.