# Large repeating background image in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, png

I'm trying to have an oversized image within a viewport container presented as a background image with a repeat style on it. The below code works for Chrome and Firefox, but when looking at it in Internet Explorer (observed in 9 and 11 on multiple machines), I'm getting an odd image tear of some sort. Anybody have a solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="map-layer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.map-layer {
width:4468px;
height:2016px;
background: #000000 url('http://www.thormx.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/rvmxgp-micro/images/world-map.png') 1px -1px repeat-x;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/75r8hgdg/1/

Note: When the background x position is set to 0, the tear effect disappears, but that defeats the purpose of starting at a specified (x,y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further searching, the solution I wound up using is referenced as a workaround in a different question [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19172628). By making the transparent image's height and width match, the artifacts go away.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the positive x position is causing the tear (very weird, most likely a bug)

Try this instead:

```
<style>
    .map {
        width:4468px;
        height:2015px;      
        padding-left: 1px;
    }
    .map-layer {
        width:4468px;
        height:2016px;
        background: url('http://www.thormx.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/rvmxgp-micro/images/world-map.png') repeat-x #000000;
        background-position: 0 -1px;
    }
</style>

<div class="map">
    <div class="map-layer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/75r8hgdg/2/ 
However, I'm still seeing the issue as I'm scrolling through the container (it disappears while I'm scrolling).

Comment: have you considered using a gif or just having a flat jpeg with a black background?

Comment: I can convert the image into a gif or jpg (not ideal, but I can), but this does not solve my issue. The gif has the same flaw the png has and the jpg does not have transparency.I have a background image that needs to bleed through (thus the world image is transparent). Although converting it to a jpg seems to address the distortion, it does not provide an acceptable solution.

Comment: more things to try: increase bit depth, output only green and black&white channel when rendering the PNG (photoshop). Also how often will you change the backgound position? I know it's a silly answer but can you just listerally have another version of this png cropped without the top 300px instead of doing -300px?